# CAExcludePath is being ignored during Visual Studio code analysis

Tags: visual-studio, static-analysis, code-analysis

I have a Visual Studio C++ application project `MyApp` and a Visual Studio C++ library project `Lib`. The `MyApp` project has `Lib` project added as a project reference, as well as `$(ProjectDir)..\Lib;` added to **Additional Include Directories**.

I have added this to `MyApp.vcxproj`:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Language)'=='C++'"> 
 <CAExcludePath>$(ProjectDir)..\Lib;$(CAExcludePath)</CAExcludePath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then I run static analysis:

```
msbuild -m /p:RunCodeAnalysis=true /p:CodeAnalysisRuleSet=NativeRecommendedRules.ruleset /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x86 MyApp.vcxproj
```

But the results contain analysis results for path `\Lib`?

I've also tried passing in the environment variable:

```
$env:CAExcludePath = "$pwd\..\Lib";msbuild -m /p:RunCodeAnalysis=true /p:CodeAnalysisRuleSet=NativeRecommendedRules.ruleset /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x86 MyApp.vcxproj
```

But this doesn't work either.

How do I exclude this whole `Lib` library from analysis results for `MyApp`? I run analysis for `Lib` separately, as it's used across a number of projects under analysis and I don't want repetitive results for `Lib` included in every report.

We are running Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same issue on VS2022, and the resolution was weird enough that I wanted to share it. Namely, I could easily reproduce the behavior you describe where `CAExcludePath` was seemingly "ignored" - I would run code analysis after adding a path to that list and still see it spit out warnings for those files. But, after I cleaned the solution and re-ran analysis, they disappeared. I believe that cached results were being returned because the source files hadn't been changed between code analysis runs - the piece that clued me into this was that if I ran analysis on a problematic project, it showed me the warnings, but once I re-ran analysis on the individual CPP files in that project, the warnings didn't appear and afterwards running analysis on the project as a whole also saw the warnings disappear.